# SwiftUI: Strange border around label when using .buttonStyle(borderless)

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app with two texts ("Hello" and "World") with different implementations that when tapped, it presents a `DetailView`. The `DetailView` shows a Button with an Image of a globe set as the `label:`, which I apply the `.buttonStyle(borderless)` modifier to. I assume this should hide any borders, however, when it's presented it has a border around it ONLY for the "Hello" implementation.

If I tap on the "World" NavigationLink to navigate to the `DetailView` the border doesn't show around the globe, which is how I expect `.buttonStyle(.borderless)` to behave.

I'm not sure what this border is and why it's only showing depending on how one navigates to it.

How can I remove this border around the globe?

[image: Tapping "Hello" shows the globe with a border around it, tapping "World" shows the globe without a border.]
[image: globe image with mysterious blue border around it.]

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingDetail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Hello")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showingDetail = true
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                    DetailView()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                }

            NavigationLink {
                DetailView()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            } label: {
                Text("World")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button() {
            print("Button Clicked")
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.blue))
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
    }
}
```

My Environment:
Xcode 15 beta 4
macOS 13.4.1

Comment: It's prob an Xcode 15 issue, I'm on 14.3 and am not seeing the border you're talking about.

Comment: Works fine on 14.3.1 for me also. Always a balancing act between adopting the latest tools and just getting your app to work how it's supposed to.